# OR logical operator in bash

Tags: bash, logical-operators

I have very dumb problem but can't wrap my head around it

```
if [[ false || false ]] ; then
        echo 'true'
else
        echo 'false'
fi
```

As per http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

> -o logical or
>
> exp1 -o exp2 returns true if either exp1 or exp2 is true.
>
> These are similar to the Bash comparison operators && and ||, used
>   within double brackets. [[ condition1 && condition2 ]]

so if both are false then it should return false? then why it prints 'true'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run those not as part of the conditional command '[[ ]]':

```
if false || false; then
        echo 'true'
else
        echo 'false'
fi
```

As for testing falses within [[ and ]]:

```
if [[ ! 1 || ! 1 ]]; then
        echo 'true'
else
        echo 'false'
fi
```

Noting that [[ false ]] is equivalent to [[ -n false ]] which makes a true condition.

If you like you could make a more apparent and valid conditional test with (( )) like this:

```
if (( 0 || 0 )); then
        echo 'true'
else
        echo 'false'
fi
```

Comment: `""` (the empty string) is probably a more canonical false value in `bash`; note that `! 0` is just as false in this context as `! 1`.

Answer (score 4):

"false" is not false. "false" is a non-empty string. Non-empty strings are true by default in `[[`.

Comment: "false" is not a keyword in `[[`.